# Flag or report?

Tags: icons, actions

When should you use flag or report, or is there a reason to always use one or the other?

In my current situation I will be using icons, let's say these two:

[image: Material Design report icon]
[image: Material Design flag icon]

But if there are only studies based on text these are also welcome.

Comment: What does flag mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## System vs social

In general use:

- Users **report** *system problems*.
- Users **flag** *community problems*.

I'm not aware of any studies on the topic, so let's think about the terms semantically.

> When I encounter a problem with your system I want to send it over to be placed in a queue of issues. I want to "report" it.
>
> When I encounter something inappropriate, offensive, harmful, or malicious I want to call your immediate attention to deal with it as quickly as possible. I want to "raise a flag" to alert you.

Like I said, it's just semantics, not a study. But if you're looking for a way distinguish the two, it's a reasonable guide.

## Context is everything

It's worth noting that this is relative to the larger system and cultural contexts. For instance, on the system side, I've worked on a couple of systems where we "flagged" things for the user. When they saw a flag in the interface, it meant that there was a pattern that needed their attention, not something they wanted to call our attention to.

Comment: [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/181495968648557) uses the term "Report" for inappropriate content (which is what I think of for "commmunity problems") and [YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2802027?hl=en) uses it somewhat interchangeably (they call it flagging but the buttons say "Report" with a flag icon).

Comment: Note that I said "general" ;-) If you're going to use both, this is the convention.

Comment: I think I agree but is there anything supporting that? I can't even find any sites using both to base it off of.

Comment: I might want to add that "flagging" is more generic, which might allow for more options, while report is fairly straight forward in which you're doing one option. I've seen this sort of behavior on iOS's mail application.

Comment: I'm not sure that users know the difference. I never thought of them in that way.

Comment: I still cannot find any studies or even anything related to flagging or reporting, so let's use this as the first go-to method!